# Why can't I use arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error

When I initialize an array in my class there are no errors being report by eclipse. However, the moment I fill in any of my array's indexes an error is reported on the semicolon where I initialize my array. I've copy pasted this array from a java tutorial site in case my problem was an user error and I still receive this error.

```
public class Test{
int[] myIntArray = new int[3]; //syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

myIntArray[0]= 1;
```

} //syntax error, insert "}" to complete class body

Comment: You're trying to call code that needs to be within a method or constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a statement, you may execute them in the main method:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myIntArray = new int[3]; 
        myIntArray[0]= 1; 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may initialize your fields in a constructor:

```
public class Test{
    int[] myIntArray = new int[3]; 

    public Test(){
        myIntArray[0] = 1; 
    }
}
```